# Python regex: Replace individual characters in a match

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to substitute every individual character found in a regex match but I can't seem to make it work.

I have a string containing parenthesized expressions that have to be replaced.

For example, `foo bar (baz)` should become `foo bar (***)`

Here is what I came up with: `re.sub(r"(\(.*?).(.*?\))", r"\1*\2", "foo bar (baz)")` Unfortunately, I can't seem to apply the substitution to every character between the parentheses. Is there any way to make this work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'foo bar (baz)'
>>> re.sub(r'(?<=\().*?(?=\))', lambda m: '*'*len(m.group()), s)
'foo bar (***)'
```

Comment: Nice use of the function feature of regexp (which far to few people know).

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I needed! I wasn't aware that .group() will return the matches during the substitution process.